# running a npm script of "devDependencies" during the postinstall

Tags: node.js, npm

I've done a script to launch during the postinstall phase of a build, It work wonderfully. My issue?

I want to put my script in a npm dependency in order to run it in any other npm project during the postinstall phase

**how can I do that cleanly?**

I was thinking of doing something like:

```
script:{
    postinstall:"node node_modules/myScript/run.js"
}
```

It work when it's in the root project but it not when I reuse my project as a dependency

I was also thinking of something like:
  script:{
        postinstall:"myScript"
    }

But I don't know how to convert a npm project into a commandline tool

(just for info, running my script add new (non-npm)dependencies to the node_modules and convert them into npm standard dependencies)

Comment: You can't do that, for the obvious reason that before the install is before the install! Could you clarify what the behaviour you're trying to implement is?

Comment: @onrsharpe  I have edited my post, tell me if it's more clear. 
I still haven't yet decided if my script should run pre or post install, because it's a script who add new dependencies. I'm open to all suggestion.

Comment: The _npm blog_ has three articles regarding _"Building a simple command line tool with npm"_ - See parts [1](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/118810260230/building-a-simple-command-line-tool-with-npm), [2](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/119317128765/adding-subcommands-to-your-command-line-tool), and [3](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/119377806820/making-your-command-line-tool-configurable)